# Using install shield from CLI ,is it possible?

Tags: installation, release, command-line-interface, installshield

### I have some existing install shield 2009 projects and every time i want to create a newer version of them i perform some specific tasks that i want to automate with a script.

This are the operations that i have to perform manually

- Change GUID
- Point to the updated packages
- Build single_exec_image

Is it possible to make this operations  from CLI on installShield 2009?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield has an [Automation Interface](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpAutomation.htm) (32bit COM based).  You can use this API to make programmatic changes to your installer project.  InstallShield also supports command line builds using [ISCmdBld.exe](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/ISCmdBldParam.htm).

Typically you do all of this in the realm of build automation using MSBuild or NAnt.   Both allow you to write custom tasks in c# that can interop to the COM automation interface.

For example I use TFS which uses MSbuild (which InstallShield has native support for via .isproj files ) to build my installer.  In this scenario I can use dynamic properties in MSBuild to generate a GUID and I can use path variable overrides to point to your source.  The build target then builds the installer.

A bunch of ways to skin this cat depending on your environment.

Comment: It was very helpful! The automation interface got everything.Thank you very much.One more question that maybe you will know.Do you know if i can by anyway call this functions through a shell script or a python file ?

Comment: found it.I can actually call all this functions from a VBscript

Comment: Yes, Python and VBSCript have ways of calling COM.  But honestly that's how I did it many years ago.  I've moved on to MSBuild mostly these days.  You might be surprised how little lines of XML it takes to declare all of this in a very stable manner.

Comment: thank you very much.I will try both of them.Do you by any chance remember how to run the .vbs script that contains the install shield API?Do you know what needs to be included or imported ?Thank you in advance

Comment: You just use CreateObject to get started. http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm